# How can I distinguish between myShortCutSettings and DefaultSettings?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto, shortcut

I'm writing a ShortCutKey in Excel VBA;

```
Application.OnKey "^s", ""            '  makes Default setting
Application.OnKey "^s", "myPro"       '  makes myPro setting
```

Sometimes I set it my own one and the other day I set it Excel default.
So..
I'd like to know whether the setting is Mine or Default, using VBA code.

And this should be through not read one of its module's contents but, some other way - I mean a real way - not a kind of workarounds but "Application.ListCommands ListAllCommands:=True" in case of MS Word.

or, If possible, How about using VSTO ? I'm kind of familiar with it, through C#.